# Properties on this.props does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can console my property on this.props. But ts shows error ts(2339).

I have tried to define the type of this.props. But 'this.props' is ReadOnly already.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Avatar} from 'antd';
import router from 'umi/router';
import styles from './index.css';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import LeftBar from '../leftbar';

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  return {
    username: state.global.username,
    login: state.global.login
  }
}
class Header extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    if(!this.props.login){
      router.push('/');
    }
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this state:'+this.state);
    console.log('this props:'+this.props);
    // router.push('/');
  }
  public render () {
    return (
      <div className={styles.navbar}>
        {/* <img src="logo.png"/> */}
        <div className={styles.title}>login</div>
        <div className={styles.userinfo} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.username}<Avatar size={"large"} icon="user" /></div>
        <LeftBar></LeftBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

In my code, 'this.props.log' and 'this.props.username' show not defined.

I want to know how to fix this error message.And how to define the type of props in Reactjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript is complaining because it is unaware of what type **`props`** should be inside of you React component. In order to specify this you can specify what type **`props`** (and **`state`**, if needed) should be. This is done easily by changing how you create the React component class, for example:

```
class Header extends React.Component<P, S> {
```

Where **`P`** specifies the property type of **`props`** and **`S`** the property type of **`state`**. If you feel like TypeScript is being annoying and don't feel like using a specific type for your **`props`** you can go ahead and do this:

```
class Header extends React.Component<any> {
```

Or if you don't want a particular type for neither **`props`** nor **`state`** you could do:

```
class Header extends React.Component<any, any> {
```

Since **`any`** will allow **`props`** and **`state`** to by anything, even stuff which are not objects, you could do the following to ensure they are at least object:

```
class Header extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
```

(**`{}`**, could also be **`Object`** here). But considering you are using TypeScript and not just JavaScript, it's probably worth specifying an type or interface for your **`props`** so you can actually utilize the typing benefits that TypeScript offers, like so:

```
type HeaderProps = {
  username: string
  login: any
  log: any
}
class Header extends React.Component<HeaderProps> {
```

Which solution you want to go for is ultimately up to you, using **`any`** will allow for more flexibility while using specific types will help your code be self-documenting and be type-safe.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have solved this problem in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a interface for prop and pass it to React.Component.

```
interface Props {
  username: any
  login: any
}

class Header extends React.Component<Props> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use constructor** [constructor()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
```